# Where does cydia store documents for tweaks?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I'm working with someone on reddit to develop an app capable of writing amiibos on iOS. I need to send a key_retail.bin into the documents folder of the app.

I enabled NFC Entitlement and then converted it to a deb so I could use it as a tweak.

The documents (via filza file manager) is no longer in Apps Manager

I also checked (root)/var/mobile/containers/data/applications

It's not there, it's also not in (root)/Applications/ (Well the .app is, but not the documents folder)

Comment: Instead of installing the app using a deb to /Applications, try installing AppSync Unified first, then install the app through Filza. (using a `.ipa` file)

Comment: @abc Its a tweak. its not meant to be used as an ios app. If it was that easy, id have done it already. Filza has a built in apps manager that gives you the locations for all the appdata. Im asking where it is when it comes to tweaks

Comment: When you access the documents directory in the app, why not just print the directory path or show it in an alert so you know exactly where it is?

Comment: @abc Well Im not too good at programming in swift, so I have limited options

Comment: Ask how to get the path of a directory in Swift on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @abc I dont know how to write swift... I wouldnt even know where to put it if someone WROTE it for me

Comment: If you're writing the code for an app that's this complex to that interfaces with amiibos on jailbroken devices, you should know some basic iOS programming, otherwise you risk breaking your iOS devices, especially since this is intended for jailbroken devices.